# openpgp2ssh (monkeysphere tool) installed with Homebrew on OS X error Can't locate Crypt/OpenSSL/Bignum.pm in @INC

Tags: homebrew, perl

I am trying to install `monkeysphere` on an OS X machine with `Homebrew`:

```
$ brew install monkeysphere
monkeysphere: Unsatisfied dependency: Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum
Homebrew does not provide Perl dependencies; install with:
  cpan -i Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

monkeysphere needs the `Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum` perl module and *Homebrew* is telling me to use the command `cpan -i Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum` in order to install that module. After I type:

```
$ cpan -i Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum
...
...
```

And install the dependency, I re-type the `brew` command:

```
$ brew install monkeysphere
==> Downloading http://archive.monkeysphere.info/debian/pool/monkeysphere/m/monkeysphere/monkeysphere_0.36.orig.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file Makefile
Hunk #5 succeeded at 62 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 85 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 88 (offset 2 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 92 (offset 2 lines).
==> make install
  /usr/local/Cellar/monkeysphere/0.36: 52 files, 416K, built in 8 seconds
$
```

Now, monkeysphere is installed, but when I run a command included in the package (e.g. `openpgp2ssh`), I get the following error:

```
$ openpgp2ssh < gpg.key 
Can't locate Crypt/OpenSSL/Bignum.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18) at /usr/local/bin/openpgp2ssh line 55.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/openpgp2ssh line 55.
```

monkeysphere is telling me that it still can't find the `Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum` perl module I have installed with `cpan`.

Why doesn't it see the dependency and how can I repair this issue?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Just tried installing monkeysphere (had to install the Bignum module too) and openpgp2ssh works for me. If you run `brew doctor` does it find any problems with your brew install?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I have just found the source of the problem. It appears that the wrong `cpan` command was issued when I installed `Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum`. It was an `/opt/local/bin/cpan` installed by MacPorts which was bound to a MacPorts' `/opt/local//bin/perl` Perl which differs from the perl used by `openpgp2ssh`. I have just installed the module with the correct `/usr/bin/cpan` using an absolute path on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was `cpan` installed with MacPorts. I had to install the module with `$ /usr/bin/cpan -i Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum`, specifying an absolute path for `cpan`.